# Python - use string literals in Oracle SQL Query

Tags: python, sql, oracle, text

I am attempting to run a SQL query on an oracle database like so:

```
import cx_Oracle as cx
import pandas as pd

un = "my username"
pw = "my password"
db = "database name"
lookup = "1232DX%"

myconn = cx.connect(un, pw, db)
cursor = myconn.cursor()

qry = """SELECT *
    FROM tableX
    WHERE tableX.code LIKE '1232DX%'"""

qry.df = pd.read_sql(qry, con = myconn)
myconn.close()
```

My issue is that it is redundant to define lookup before the query and use the value in the query itself. I would like to just be able to type

```
WHERE tableX.code LIKE lookup
```

and have the value `1232DX%` substituted into my query.

I imagine there is a straightforward way to do this in Python, but I am hardly an expert so I thought I would ask someone here.  All suggestions are welcome.  If there is a better way to do this than what I have shown please include it. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use the same syntax as when passing parameters to `cursor.execute()`.

```
qry = """SELECT *
    FROM tableX
    WHERE tableX.code LIKE :pattern"""
qry.df = pd.read_sql(qry, con = myconn, params={":pattern": lookup})
```